# ADB tcpip works over IPv6

Tags: android, powershell, tcp, adb, ipv6

I'm trying to connect to my device over tcpip but the command `adb tcpip 5555` starts the listening port in all interfaces over IPv6.

```
PS C:\Users\David> adb -s 5200bade8d87c567 tcpip 5555
restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

PS C:\Users\David> adb -s 5200bade8d87c567 shell netstat -ant
Active Internet connections (established and servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:37536      13.107.42.14:443        ESTABLISHED
tcp      130      0 192.168.1.97:36988      216.58.211.234:443      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:36984      31.13.83.36:443         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:38210      31.13.83.4:443          ESTABLISHED
tcp      130      0 192.168.1.97:42996      216.58.215.138:443      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:59850      172.217.17.4:443        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:60716      31.13.83.8:443          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:60712      31.13.83.8:443          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:37154      216.58.211.234:443      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.97:36980      31.13.83.36:443         ESTABLISHED
### Here is the adbd
tcp6       0      0 :::5555                 :::*                    LISTEN
###
tcp6      32      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:47634 ::ffff:44.236.220.4:443 CLOSE_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:60088 ::ffff:172.217.168.:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:55526 ::ffff:216.58.211.2:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:56700 ::ffff:172.217.168.:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:57900 ::ffff:142.250.184.:443 TIME_WAIT
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:46458 ::ffff:172.217.168.:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:49284 ::ffff:142.250.185.:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:57066 ::ffff:216.58.205.2:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:53960 ::ffff:172.217.21.1:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:57052 ::ffff:172.217.18.4:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:37164 ::ffff:216.58.211.2:443 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50014 ::ffff:74.125.133.:5228 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.:42466 ::ffff:172.217.17.3:443 ESTABLISHED

PS C:\Users\David> adb -s 5200bade8d87c567 shell ip -f inet addr show wlan0
11: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.97/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

PS C:\Users\David> adb connect 192.168.1.97:5555
cannot connect to 192.168.1.97:5555: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (10060)
```

I'm also trying to use the IPv6 address to connect but doesn't work either.

```
PS C:\Users\David> adb -s 5200bade8d87c567 shell ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::d27f:a0ff:fecc:fd5f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

PS C:\Users\David> adb connect [fe80::d27f:a0ff:fecc:fd5f]:5555
cannot connect to fe80::d27f:a0ff:fecc:fd5f:5555: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
```

Is there any option to start the server over IPv4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was connected to the VPN (Cisco AnyConnect).